# SPARTA-kick it off a cliff: [SOFTWARE-REC]

Tags: discussion

Currently we have [eight questions tagged](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/software-rec) with [software-rec]. Three are closed and the majority have been migrated from SuperUser so can it, y'know, burn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ooh, I like this game.

[dynamic](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/dynamic) Dynamic **what**?

[memory](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/memory) [ram](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/ram) Synonym candidate

In fact...

http://data.stackexchange.com/serverfault/query/59684/top-tags-by-closed-question-ratio

**BURN THEM ALL**

Comment: all 4990 of them ?

Comment: @Iain It's a goal... we don't need no stinking tags! I suppose it might be better to start with everything that has a ratio > .5. Those are looking like a sad bunch. [tag:cheap-hosting], [tag:wowza], [tag:operations]... But yes, I did not do a limit when I wrote the query.

Comment: RAM is memory but memory is not necessarily RAM.

Comment: My memory is failing, can I get a new one?

Comment: @Andrew, don't worry about it. When it gets bad enough you'll be unaware of it.

Comment: @JohnGardeniers Different definitions has no bearing on the nature of questions being tagged in a way that uses them interchangeably.